# Ruby. Explicit and implicit blocks

Tags: ruby

I am learning Ruby on RubyMonk. And I cannot perform this lesson:

We have a method called `filter` that accepts an explicitly passed block. We look to the block to tell us whether a value from the array should be accepted or rejected.

The `Array#select` method does exactly this but requires an implicit block. Try converting the explicit block into an implicit block and passing it on to `Array#select`.

```
def filter(array, block)
  return array.select # Your code here
end
```

What I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def filter(array, block)
  return array.select(&block)
end
```

Note that the answers for each problem are accessible from the page. Simply click the link titled "See the Solution"

Comment: WTF!!! I thought what I must define a block! block = lambda {||...} or something else! and define array. Thank you! it work!